# Concat and loop functions

Tags: sql-server, loops, concatenation

I have this problem:
For each plan that start with M and A, I need to add 3 additional chars to it and keep the original. Also, plans that start with T needs to stay the same:
For example:

```
M_VA_K15CVA
M_VA_M20CVA
M_VA_T234
```

should be

```
M_VA_K15CVA
M_VA_K15CVA_V1
M_VA_K15CVA_V2
M_VA_K15CVA_V3
M_VA_M20CVA
M_VA_M20CVA_V1
M_VA_M20CVA_V2
M_VA_M20CVA_V3
M_VA_TNT10-VA
```

Any hints on what should I use to do this file? Thank you

Comment: Which version of SQL Server? This is going to be a combination of `CASE` and `ROW_NUMBER()`, assuming `ROW_NUMBER()` is available to you.

Comment: this is a textbook example of why you should not concatenate different data into a single field, but should store each portion in a different columns and at presentation time, stick them back together.

Answer (score 0):

You can expand a list into a larger list by JOINing to a derived table with a lose JOIN condition. Here is code which meets your needs, assuming that you meant "M" and "K" in your question, not "M" and "A", which didn't seem to match your example.

```
DECLARE @Plans TABLE
(
    PlanID varchar(50)
);
INSERT INTO @Plans (PlanID) VALUES ('M_VA_K15CVA');
INSERT INTO @Plans (PlanID) VALUES ('M_VA_M20CVA');
INSERT INTO @Plans (PlanID) VALUES ('M_VA_T234');

SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN RowValue IS NULL OR RowValue = 0 THEN
            PlanID
        ELSE
            PlanID + '_V' + CONVERT(varchar,RowValue)
    END AS NewPlanID
FROM        @Plans
LEFT JOIN   (
                SELECT 0 AS RowValue
                UNION ALL SELECT 1
                UNION ALL SELECT 2
                UNION ALL SELECT 3
            ) AS RowExpander
ON          RIGHT(LEFT(PlanID,6),1) IN ('M','K');
```